# DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm quite new to the try catch and exception handling. I want my program to catch the exception when the directory or file is not found. 
Whenever I run the program I get the error "DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled by user code - An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occured in something.dll but was not handled in user code"

I can see that Visual Studio breaks at the DirectoryNotFoundDirection, any ideas?

```
try {
    LiveDownloadOperation operation = await connectClient.CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync(filePath);
    var result = await operation.StartAsync();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException filEx) {
   Debug.WriteLine(filEx.Message);
   throw filEx;
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirEx) {
   Debug.WriteLine(dirEx.Message);
   throw;
}
catch (IOException ioEx) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ioEx.Message);
    throw ioEx;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

EDIT: to show code inside try

Comment: Can you show the code in the `try` block please?

Comment: Well, you re-throw it. That means that although you did log it, the exception is still out there travelling up the call stack unhandled.

Comment: in your `try` block, you can also check first if the directory exists. if it doesn't you can either create it, or throw an exception or do something else, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the directory does not exist (or has permissions problems, etc.), it throws an DirectoryNotFoundException.

Which you handle, then reraise -- because of the, the debugger rightly says that the exception is not handled.